# How to move/drag a GUITree node to another sibiling node in SAP

Tags: c#, drag-and-drop, selenium-ide, sap-gui

In SAP GUI application I need to automate the dragging of a node in GuiTree and dropping onto another node.

The type of element is shown as below:

```
(GuiShell (122) - SubType: Tree)
session.findById("wnd[0]/shellcont/shellcont/shell/shellcont[0]/shell/shellcont[1]/shell[1]").selectNode "   3".
```

Is there any way to drag?

Answer (score 0):

You can't. Choose another software to automate this kind of user action. Search the Web for a list of tools. You will need the coordinates of `GuiTree` nodes in number of pixels, that you may retrieve with the methods `GetNodeTop`, `GetNodeLeft`, etc.